# Node of redshift cluster in private subnet has public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-redshift

I am new to terraform and using it I created a Redshift cluster in a private subnet. The public accessibility option is set to No. I was assuming that there wont be any public IP associated with this cluster however when I see the properties tab of Redshift cluster in AWS console I see a public IP under Node IP addresses.Below are the configuration files for VPC and Redshift cluster.

```
1. VPC Config

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

terraform {
  required_version = " > 0.12"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "aws-vpc-terraform-custom" {
  cidr_block = "10.200.0.0/16"
  tags = {
      vpcType = "custom-vpc-terraform"
      }

}

resource "aws_subnet" "aws-subnet-private-subnet" {
  cidr_block = "10.200.1.0/24"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
  tags = {
    subnetType = "terraform-private-subnet"
  }


}

resource "aws_subnet" "aws-subnet-public-subnet" {
  cidr_block = "10.200.2.0/24"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
  tags = {
    subnetType = "terraform-public-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "terraform-internet-gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
  tags = {
    gateway = "terraform-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "terraform-route-table-public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.terraform-internet-gateway.id
  }
  tags = {
    routTable = "terraform-public-routetable"
  }
}




resource "aws_route_table" "terraform-route-table-private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
  tags = {
    routetable ="terraform-private-routetable"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "terraform-private-subnet-route-assoc" {
   subnet_id = aws_subnet.aws-subnet-private-subnet.id
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.terraform-route-table-private.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "terraform-public-subnet-route-assoc" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.terraform-route-table-public.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.aws-subnet-public-subnet.id
}


resource "aws_redshift_subnet_group" "redshift_subnet_group_name" {
  name = "terraform-redshift-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.aws-subnet-private-subnet.id]
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
   bucket = "nyeisterraformXXXX"
    key = "vpc/s3/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"

    dynamodb_table = "terraform-up-and-running-locks-XXXX"
    encrypt = true
  }
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.id
}

output "vpc_arn" {
  value = aws_vpc.aws-vpc-terraform-custom.arn
}

output "private_subnet_id" {
  value = aws_subnet.aws-subnet-private-subnet.id
}

output "public_subnet_id" {
  value = aws_subnet.aws-subnet-public-subnet.id
}

output "redshift_subnet_group_output"  {
  value = aws_redshift_subnet_group.redshift_subnet_group_name.name
}


2. Redshift cluster config

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "> 0.12"

}

//Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
//provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
//silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
//sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.
//
//Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from
//expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a
//mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only
//to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence.


// Adding the remote and removing local state config
/*
data "terraform_remote_state" "aws_iam_role" {
  backend = "local"

  config=  {
    path = "${path.module}/../aws_iam_role/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "aws_vpc" {
  backend = "local"

  config = {
    path = "${path.module}/../aws_custom_vpc/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
*/

data "terraform_remote_state" "aws_iam_role" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = "nyeisterraformXXXX"
    key = "iamrole/s3/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "aws_vpc" {

  backend = "s3"

  config = {
      bucket = "nyeisterraformXXXX"
      key = "vpc/s3/terraform.tfstate"
      region = "us-east-2"

  }
}

resource "aws_redshift_cluster" "cluster_redshift_cluster" {
  cluster_identifier = "qa-redshift-cluster"
  node_type = "dc2.large"
  database_name = "qawarehouse"
  cluster_type = "single-node"
  port = "5439"
  master_username = <user_name>
  master_password = <password>
  iam_roles = [data.terraform_remote_state.aws_iam_role.outputs.iam_role_arn]
  #cluster_security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_security_group.arn]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.my_security_group.id]
  cluster_subnet_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_vpc.outputs.redshift_subnet_group_output
  publicly_accessible = "false"
  depends_on = [aws_security_group.my_security_group]
  final_snapshot_identifier = "false"
  skip_final_snapshot = "true"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "my_security_group" {
  name = "redshift_security_group"
  description = "The security group for redshift"
  vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  ingress {
    from_port = 5439
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 5439
    cidr_blocks = ["X.X.X.X/XX"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
  Name ="Redshift_Security_Group"
  }

}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
   bucket = "nyeisterraformXXXX"
    key = "redshift/s3/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"

    dynamodb_table = "terraform-up-and-running-locks-XXXX"
    encrypt = true
  }
}


output "database_url" {
  value = aws_redshift_cluster.cluster_redshift_cluster.endpoint
}
```

I tried to ping it but couldn't since the security group doesn't have ICMP enabled I guess.Am I missing something in the configuration file or its default behavior for node to have public IP address.Can you someone please help me out.Thank you.

Comment: Resources in a private subnet will _not_ be accessible from the Internet, even if they have a Public IP address.

Comment: Thank you .I tried traceroute on the IP and it was not reachable.